# Angular 2 custom form validation working only after user clear the textbox value

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to validate my input box immediately after the input box gets blur. But some how the validation message only appears when i write something in textbox and than delete it.

Here's my HTML template;

```html
<input type="text"
placeholder="First Name"
class="form-control"
name="firstName"
id="firstName"                                       
[ngModel]="typeValidation.firstName"
#firstName="ngModel"
(blur)="firstNameBlur(firstName.value)"
autofocus
required>
                                            
<small [hidden]="firstName.valid || (firstName.pristine && !f2.submitted)" class="text-danger">
     First Name is required.
</small>
```

Here's my typescript;

```
firstNameBlur(value:string) {

    if (value == "" || value == undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it working as you expected, you should use `untouched` instead of `pristine`, like this:

```
<small [hidden]="firstName.valid || (firstName.untouched && !f2.submitted)"
       class="text-danger">
  First Name is required.
</small>
```

or using ***ngIf** (IMHO, it's really better):

```
<small *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.touched || f2.submitted)"
       class="text-danger">
  First Name is required.
</small>
```

[***WORKING DEMO***](https://plnkr.co/edit/nFpcRHhEU35hu00nIU3T?p=info)

Note that you don't need `(blur)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are binding to the blur event? The required attribute should cause Angular to automatically validate the required field when the user leaves the field.

And what is that code doing? Since the `firstNameBlur()` is executed on an event ... returning false is setting preventDefault. (See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) Is that what is intended?

Try removing the blur event and see if it works without it. If so, then you don't need the firstNameBlur method.

Comment: it does not automatically validate the field when user leaves the field. but it validates only when user type something in it and than clear it. When user leaves that field empty without typing anything, it doesn't validate it. i want to validate when user leaves the empty field either the field is manipulated or not!

Comment: Yes, that is how the default validation normally works. Did you remove the blur event and it still does not work? Can you build a plunker to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Yes i tried to remove the blur event. but still it is not working!

Comment: Could you build a plunker that demonstrates your issue? You can start with this: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue